# How do I get the textfields and the labels to sit in a 7x3 grid?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, grid-layout, border-layout

The first column in my grid always comes out right but then the rest begin replacing the other cells. Also the border layout does not seem to be functioning. I do not know what the problem is. It should have the title on top, a 7x3 grid in the center and the buttons on the bottom. Please help! Thank you!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class GUI extends JFrame{

    private JPanel mainPanel,titlePanel, fieldPanel, buttonPanel;

    private JLabel title, teams, totalP, wlt;

    private JTextField team1, team2, team3, team4, team5, team6, total1, total2, total3, total4, total5, total6, wlt1, wlt2, wlt3, wlt4, wlt5, wlt6;

    private JButton read, calc, champWin, earthCW, exit;

    final private int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;
    final private int WINDOW_WIDTH = 900;

    public GUI(){

        buildtitlePanel();
        buildfieldPanel();
        buildbuttonPanel();
        buildmainPanel();

        setTitle("Desert Soccer League");
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    private void buildmainPanel() {

        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        mainPanel.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        add(mainPanel);

    }

    private void buildtitlePanel() {

        titlePanel = new JPanel();

        title = new JLabel();

        title.setText("2014 Desert Soccer League Totals");

        titlePanel.add(title);



    }

    private void buildfieldPanel() {

        fieldPanel = new JPanel();

        fieldPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 3));

        teams = new JLabel();
        teams.setText("Teams");

        totalP = new JLabel();
        totalP.setText("Total Points");

        wlt = new JLabel();
        wlt.setText("Win-Loss-Tie");

        team1 = new JTextField(10);
        team2 = new JTextField(10);
        team3 = new JTextField(10);
        team4 = new JTextField(10);
        team5 = new JTextField(10);
        team6 = new JTextField(10);

        total1 = new JTextField(10);
        total2 = new JTextField(10);
        total3 = new JTextField(10);
        total4 = new JTextField(10);
        total5 = new JTextField(10);
        total6 = new JTextField(10);

        wlt1 = new JTextField(10);
        wlt2 = new JTextField(10);
        wlt3 = new JTextField(10);
        wlt4 = new JTextField(10);
        wlt5 = new JTextField(10);
        wlt6 = new JTextField(10);

        team1.setEditable(false);
        team2.setEditable(false);
        team3.setEditable(false);
        team4.setEditable(false);
        team5.setEditable(false);
        team6.setEditable(false);

        total1.setEditable(false);
        total2.setEditable(false);
        total3.setEditable(false);
        total4.setEditable(false);
        total5.setEditable(false);
        total6.setEditable(false);

        wlt1.setEditable(false);
        wlt2.setEditable(false);
        wlt3.setEditable(false);
        wlt4.setEditable(false);
        wlt5.setEditable(false);
        wlt6.setEditable(false);

        fieldPanel.add(teams);
        fieldPanel.add(team1);
        fieldPanel.add(team2);
        fieldPanel.add(team3);
        fieldPanel.add(team4);
        fieldPanel.add(team5);
        fieldPanel.add(team6);

        fieldPanel.add(totalP);
        fieldPanel.add(total1);
        fieldPanel.add(total2);
        fieldPanel.add(total3);
        fieldPanel.add(total4);
        fieldPanel.add(total5);
        fieldPanel.add(total6);

        fieldPanel.add(wlt);
        fieldPanel.add(wlt1);
        fieldPanel.add(wlt2);
        fieldPanel.add(wlt3);
        fieldPanel.add(wlt4);
        fieldPanel.add(wlt5);
        fieldPanel.add(wlt6);



    }

    private void buildbuttonPanel() {

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 5));

        read = new JButton();
        calc = new JButton();
        champWin = new JButton();
        earthCW = new JButton();
        exit = new JButton();

        read.setText("Read Input File");
        read.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

        calc.setText("Calculate Points");
        calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

        champWin.setText("Championship Winner");
        champWin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

        earthCW.setText("Earth Cup Winner");
        earthCW.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

        exit.setText("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

        buttonPanel.add(read);
        buttonPanel.add(calc);
        buttonPanel.add(champWin);
        buttonPanel.add(earthCW);
        buttonPanel.add(exit);



    }


}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a JTable. A table is easier to work with because you don't need to create all those text fields. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    mainPanel = new JPanel();

    mainPanel.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

By default a `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout`. If you want to use a `BorderLayout`, then you need to set the layout on the panel:

```
    mainPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
```

The GridLayout fills out the rows first so the code should be:

```
fieldPanel.add(teams);
fieldPanel.add(totalP);
fieldPanel.add(wlt);

fieldPanel.add(team1);
fieldPanel.add(total1);
fieldPanel.add(wlt1);
...
```

Also note that in your code you are adding the total? fields twice (which won't do anything), instead of the team? fields.

Another way to specify the grid is to just use:

```
fieldPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
```

This tells the grid to add 3 components to each row then move on to the next row. This way you don't have to worry about the exact number of rows.

Comment: Thank you, however even though I changed the border layout in the panel, it still does not give me the grid that I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To add to camickr answer you're also adding the same total fields multiple times, so change this:

```
fieldPanel.add(teams);
fieldPanel.add(total1);
fieldPanel.add(total2);
fieldPanel.add(total3);
fieldPanel.add(total4);
fieldPanel.add(total5);
fieldPanel.add(total6);
```

to

```
fieldPanel.add(teams);
fieldPanel.add(team1);
fieldPanel.add(team2);
fieldPanel.add(team3);
fieldPanel.add(team4);
fieldPanel.add(team5);
fieldPanel.add(team6);
```

This is what is causing your display issue.

Your code should look like:

```
fieldPanel.add(teams);
fieldPanel.add(totalP);
fieldPanel.add(wlt);
fieldPanel.add(team1);
fieldPanel.add(total1);
fieldPanel.add(wlt1);
fieldPanel.add(team2);
fieldPanel.add(total2);
fieldPanel.add(wlt2);
// etc.
```